# Почему не устанавливаются зависимости?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, npm

Выполняю команду `npm init --yes`, затем записываю зависимости в файл `package.json`
Вот какой он: `

```
{
  "name": "webpack-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.12.5",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "vue": "*",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.3",
    "vue-loader": "*",
    "vue-style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "*"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}`
```

После выполняю команду npm install и вот появляются какие-то ошибки, что с этим делать?

```
npm install
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1: �  Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-en
v now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug inste
ad of jade
npm WARN deprecated constantinople@3.0.2: Please update to at least constantinople 3.1.1
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer

> node-sass@3.13.1 install c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node

Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'c:\\OSPanel\\domains\\vue_test\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@8.11.2 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\which\which.js:13:1
2)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\which\which.js:13:1
2)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (c:\\OSPanel\\domains\\v
ue_test\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (c:\\OSPanel\\domains\\vue_test\\node_modules\\which\
\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (c:\\OSPanel\\domains\\vue_test\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at c:\\
OSPanel\\domains\\vue_test\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at c:\\OSPanel\\domains\\vue_test\\node_
modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at c:\\OSPanel\\domains\\vue_test\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n
   at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\which\which.js:13:1
2)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python { Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\which\which.js:13:1
2)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python\n    at getNotFoundError (c:\\OSPanel\\domains\\vu
e_test\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (c:\\OSPanel\\domains\\vue_test\\node_modules\\which\\
which.js:68:19)\n    at E (c:\\OSPanel\\domains\\vue_test\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at c:\\O
SPanel\\domains\\vue_test\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at c:\\OSPanel\\domains\\vue_test\\node_m
odules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at c:\\OSPanel\\domains\\vue_test\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n
  at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\config
ure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configu
re.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\OSPanel\\domains\\vue_test\\node_modules\\node-gy
p\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsa
ss_library="
gyp ERR! cwd c:\OSPanel\domains\vue_test\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN vue-loader@15.2.4 requires a peer of vue-template-compiler@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must in
stall peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN babel-loader@6.4.1 requires a peer of webpack@1 || 2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc but none is install
ed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@4.1.1 requires a peer of webpack@^2 || ^2.2.0-rc.0 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^1.12.6 but none is
 installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer depend
encies yourself.
npm WARN vue_test@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN vue_test@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin",
"arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Home\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-07T14_26_21_521Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Необходимо `python` добавить в переменную окружения `PATH`

Comment: `Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node":` -- а вручную скачивается?

Comment: Версия ноды какая?

Comment: @PavelMayorov v8.11.2

Comment: @Евгений так и думал...

Comment: @PavelMayorov и что это значит?)

Comment: @Евгений читайте ответы внизу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пакет `node-sass` версии 3.13.1 требует чтобы node.js была не новее 7й версии. Если у вас более новая нода - обновите этот пакет.

Answer (score 1):

`npm install` не работает, так как не удается скачать `node-sass v3.13.1` с GitHub.

Попробуйте установить новую версию с помощью `npm install -D node-sass`